# Formalizing a proof for the Divison Algorithm Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, order-theory

I've been reading through a book on introductory group theory/abstract algebra and I've been having trouble understanding how to go about proving a problem that uses this theorem dealing with the order of groups and the law of exponents:

"Theorem 2: Division Algorithm if m and n are integers and n is positive, there exists unique integers q and r such that:

$m = nq + r$

and

$0 \le r \lt n  $ "

I have the exercise problem stating that if $\phi$ is a group with identity element $e$, and $x ∈ \phi$; then suppose $|x| = 150$ and that $|x^{15}| = 10$ . Prove this is possible and that it can be proved generally. And i think i have the idea of how it works, but don't think i'm using the correct steps and/or reasoning to my steps

my idea:

$e = x^{150}$  ---------> definition of $|x| = 150$ and that applying the order preserves the footprint

$= (x^{15})^{10}$ -------> rules of exponents

$= e$ --------------> definition of  $|x^{15}| = 10$ and that applying the order preserves the footprint

and my thoughts for proving it more generally would be:

$x^{m} = x^{nq}x^{r} = x^{r} ∈ [1,x,…,x_{n−1}]$ with roughly the same steps

Comment: To me it's not clear what you are assuming and what you have to prove.

Comment: "$0 \ge r \lt n  $" should be edited into "$0 \le r \lt n  $".

Comment: @user750041 i was assuming that $|x|=150$ and assuming that $|x^{15}| = 10$, then proving this is consistent

Comment: Your title is "Formalizing a proof **for** the Divison Algorithm Theorem".  That implies you are trying to prove the division algorithm theorem.  But the body of your question is asking nothing of the sort.  What *IS* your question?

Comment: @fleablood maybe I should've stated that it was for an instance of the Division Algorithm, bc it's not that i don't understand how it works but i lack the knowledge of how to formally prove it. So my question was how do i formally explain the steps i'm showing such they're both consistent and accurate

Comment: What you did is a good start.  As $x^{150}=e$ then $(x^{15})^{10} = x^{150}=e$.  What you have to *also* show is that if $0< k < 10$ then $(x^{15})^k \ne e$.

Comment: @fleablood oh okay thanks!! that makes sense since there can't be a remainder outside of the order that also produces the identity. so does that then also infer: that the order of every element of a group (lets say $Z_{100}$) is then a divisor of 100 ?  since by the definition of order it states that the order is the least positive number of times the element applied to itself produces the identity, and thus doesn't allow for remainders thus making it a divisor (since by definition it divides 100 with no remainder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|a| = m$ means i) $a^m = e$ and ii) if $0 < k < m$ then $a^k \ne e$

So if $|x| =150$ then

i) $(x^{15})^{10} = x^{150} =e$ (because $|x|=150$ so $x^{150} = e$).

ii) If $0 < k < 10$ then $0 < 15k < 150$ and $(x^{15})^k = x^{15k} \ne e$ (because $|x|= 150$ so when $15k< 150$ we know $x^{15k}\ne e$).

So by definition $|x^{15}| = 10$.

So if $|x| =150$ is possible, then $|x^{15}| = 10$ is inevitable.  And $|x|=150$ is clearly possible (for example: If $\phi = \mathbb Z_{150}$ and $x = 1$....)